# Weka: Array Index out of bounds exception with CSV files

Tags: weka

I get an unfriendly ArrayOutOfBoundsException when I try to input a CSV file to Weka. But it works fine when I use the same in the GUI.

```
pvadrevu@MacPro~$ java -Xmx2048m -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -t "some.csv" -d temp.model

Refreshing GOE props...
[KnowledgeFlow] Loading properties and plugins...
[KnowledgeFlow] Initializing KF...
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.setPriors(Evaluation.java:3843)
    weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1503)
    weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:650)
    weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.runClassifier(AbstractClassifier.java:359)
    weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic.main(Logistic.java:1134)

    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.setPriors(Evaluation.java:3843)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1503)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:650)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.runClassifier(AbstractClassifier.java:359)
    at weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic.main(Logistic.java:1134)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the new versions of Weka donot handle CSV files through command line. There are two options:

1. Revert back to an older version of Weka. 3.6.11 works fine for me while 3.7.11 does not.
2. Convert the CSV files to ARFF. It can be done using the Weka GUI.